# backbone.js - No model inheritance after restoring from localStorage

Tags: inheritance, collections, model, backbone.js, local-storage

After restoring my collection from localStorage overwritten methods (getLabel() in following example) are no longer called. The base method is called instead. I think the problem is, that I tell the collection to use the BaseModel. But how to change the collection to work with the models KeywordLog and CommentLog?

I use the following model inheritance:

```
var BaseLog = Backbone.Model.extend({   
    defaults: {
        timecode: null,
        color: null,
        isRange: false,
    },  
    getLabel: function() {
        return 'base';
    }
});

var KeywordLog = BaseLog.extend({   
    defaults: _.extend({}, BaseLog.prototype.defaults, {
        keyword: null,      
    }),     
    getLabel: function() {
        return 'keyword';
    }
});

var CommentLog = BaseLog.extend({   
    defaults: _.extend({}, BaseLog.prototype.defaults, {
        text: null,     
    }), 
    getLabel: function() {
        return 'comment';
    }
});

var Loglist = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // This might be the problem after restoring drom localStorage..? 
    model: BaseLog,
    localStorage: new Store("storage")
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections will only work with a single model type. I suggest you switch to a single model and include `label` as an attribute.

```
var Log = Backbone.Model.extend({   
    defaults: {
        timecode: null,
        color: null,
        isRange: false,
        label: 'base',
        text: null
    },
    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this);
    },
    getLabel: function() {
        return this.label;
    }
});

log = new Log;
log.set({ text: 'keyword here', label: 'keyword' })
log2 = new Log;
log2.set({ text: 'comment here', label: 'comment' })
```